# IIS7 redirect https to http except 1 page

Tags: iis-7

I have a rule

```
<rule name="HTTPS to HTTP Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

that redirects ALL HTTPS to HTTP however I now need 1 page to be HTTPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have assumed your page that is to force HTTPS is login.aspx.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS for 1 page " stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)/login.aspx" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Others Force HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="((.*))" negate="true" />
        <conditions>  
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try regular expression below: This will match everything with https except for help.html page.

```
^[hH][Tt]{2}[pP][Ss](?!.*help.html).*$
```